# Detectar y cortar una string si contiene un determinado formato

Tags: java, string, formato, apex

¿Hay algún método o forma de detectar si una String contiene otra con un determinado formato?

00000000 <- El formato es este donde los ceros pueden ser cualquier numero, entonces estariamos hablando que cuando se encuentres 8 números seguidos se almacenen esos números. Se tienen que discriminar por ejemplo cadenas de 9 números que podrían ser números de teléfono.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes!. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para que conozcas el formato de preguntas que se alinean con la temática del sitio y por qué es importante proveer un escenario lo más detallado posible (incluyendo el código y, si es posible, un [mcve].
Por otra parte, más centrada en tu pregunta, puedes usar una expresión regular para encontrar esos 8 dígitos exactamente y modificar el texto.

Comment: Lo que buscas se hace con expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien han comentado se puede hacer un una expresión regular.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String frase = "En la siguiente cadena: 12345678 hay 8 numeros";

    String patternStr = "[^0-9][0-9]{8}[^0-9]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(frase);

    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Se ha encontrado una cadena que coincide con el patrón: " + matcher.group());
    }
}
```

En ese fragmento de código uso la expresión "[^0-9][0-9]{8}[^0-9]". Esta expresión va a buscar fragmento en la cadena de texto que tenga exactamente:

1. Un carácter que no este comprendido entre el 0 y el 9
2. Un carácter comprendido entre el 0 y el 9 y multiplicamos esta condición por 8
3. Un carácter que no este comprendido entre el 0 y el 9

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html